# Content Rotator With Content Management

Tags: asp.net, html, content-management, adrotator

I am developing a website that will have content rotator in one of the pages. The only dynamic part of the website will be the news part. I want to add a content management page for the news. The news items will be edited by the user and will be published. The rest of the website wont be affected.

There are many free content sliders but unfortunately none of the ones i found has a content management system. I am developing the website in asp .net. I dont want to use a very big content management system for such a small job. Is there any free or commercial with a small price product that can fullfil my requirements ?

Thanks

Comment: why you care to write an answer if it wont help anyone. I already coded all the website before. Now I have a new need and I didnt want to waste time if there is an already made component. I can even pay it. it doesnt have to be free.

Comment: Sorry. I have a "DIY" attitude that people don't seem to share. Good luck, but I don't know of any free ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find via my profile link that I made for programmers. There are other great ones too like Page Lime which is great for designers. You could try some open source ones for ASP.NET like Orchard CMS or DotNetNuke. It all depends on your comfort level. I do prefer the cloud ones myself but I'm a bit impartial as I hate installing things and having to learn frameworks.

Comment: sorry, to be specific, the one I did has an image rotator built in but I don't mind helping you with a content rotator as I'm adding new features in. There is also Surreal CMS that is good but its FTP-based but does have a repeater which could do content rotation as well.